# What is Unix find command's default ordering?

Tags: shell, unix

I was searching through the man pages for find for clues of UNIX find command default ordering.

Appreciate if anyone knows this.

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` just peeks the files and subdirectories as they appear in the directories, just like `ls -U` when this option is available.

Comment: So there is no guarantee of any order? Thanks.

Comment: Precisely.      .       .       .

Answer (score 2):

The find command uses the [`opendir()` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) to get listings in a directory, which returns a directory stream, and it traverses the stream and evaluates each entry. The ones that matches criteria are returned in the order they are evaluated. Therefore, the order you get from the `find` command is how the underlying filesystem presents them.

Comment: Thank you Jon Lin for the explanation and reference.