# BASH: How to get files (by find) sorted and line by line into a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, find

I need a list of files in the defined directory: `find "~/WorkDir" -maxdepth 1 -type f`
This shall be stored in a variable, line by line and sorted:

```
~/WorkDir/File1.txt
~/WorkDir/File 2.txt
~/WorkDir/File 9.txt
```

I tried `WorkFiles=$(find "$WorkDir" -maxdepth 1 -type f)`but this is one line for all files without sorting.

Comment: please update the question with more details; in particular, the `sort` call you're using and how you determined the results are stored as a single line in the variable (eg, `typeset -p var`? `echo $var`? `echo "$var"`?, something else?)

Comment: Technically, find output *is* sorted, it's just not usually a very useful ordering. https://serverfault.com/a/181815 https://stackoverflow.com/a/11556156

Comment: You may have executed `echo $WorkFiles` which will print the results in one line. Please try `echo "$WorkFiles"` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
printf -v WorkFiles '%s\n' ~/WorkDir/*
echo "$WorkFiles"
```

or

```
WorkFiles=
for file in ~/WorkDir/*; do
    [[ -f $file ]] && WorkFiles+=$file$'\n'
done
```

if only regular files are of interest.

Comment: this is nice, but doesn't just list the files

Comment: @jhnc Indeed. This assumes the directory contains only regular files. Perhaps `~/WorkDir/*.txt` is better if only the filenames ending with `.txt` are of interest.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. But it doesn't help: I  need only the files (*.*) and nothing from subdirectories.

Comment: @StOMicha See updated answer

Comment: @M. Nejat Aydin, Thanks a lot for the update. It works, but I'm wondering, why (in both options) all files are listed in one line. I'd need one line for each file ...

Comment: Solved by comment @tshiono: `echo "$WorkFiles"` instead `echo $WorkFiles`