# How to move and list one folder of many in one line

Tags: bash, filesystems

I have spent quite few hours trying to find a way to move a folder out of many using `find`, `tail`, `xargs`, and `mv` in Linux. My "one" liner works but it is rather ugly ane inefficient because repeats code.

This is what works:

```
find /volume/downloads/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime -30  | tail -n1 | xargs -i echo "{}" \
&& find /volume/downloads/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime -30  | tail -n1 | xargs -i \
mv "{}"  /archives/recent/downloads/
```

The first find shows the folder to move and the second executes the moving.

Would anybody advise how to do this folder moving and messaging in a more elegant way?

EDIT
The idea is moving a folder from one server to another (one of them is mounted in the first). The one liner - that will be called from `cron` everyday, will move only one folder per day, from server A to server B. But I need feedback of the folder that is being moved. I want to show it on the screen.

Comment: Assign the result of `find` to a variable. Then you can echo it and move it.

Comment: "how to do this folder moving and messaging in a more elegant way?" I think you can do this with one `find` and no other commands.  `find /volume/downloads/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime -30 -print -exec mv {} /archives/recent/downloads`.  The only thing that doesn't do is `tail -n 1` which I suppose is probably for debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your existing code works, this might be what you're trying to do (untested):

```
find /volume/downloads/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime -30 | tail -1 | xargs -i bash -c 'echo "{}"; mv -- "{}" /archives/recent/downloads/'
```

Comment: Bash is like Jedi magic! Never ceases to impress me.

Comment: The code contains a code injection vulnerability similar to [Bash Pitfalls #52 (find . -exec sh -c 'echo {}' \;)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#find_._-exec_sh_-c_.27echo_.7B.7D.27_.2BAFw.3B).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
find /volume/downloads/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime -30 -print -exec mv -- {} /archives/recent/downloads/ \; -quit
```

- `-mindepth 1` is to prevent the code trying to move `/volume/downloads/`.
- `-print` causes `find` itself to print the path being moved, avoiding the need for an `echo` (or, much better, `printf`) in shell code.  An alternative is to drop this option and use the `-v` option with `mv`.
- `-quit` causes `find` to exit is soon as it has executed a successful `mv`, ensuring that it will only move one directory.

Comment: It doesn't work when you add `tail`: `find /volume/downloads/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime -30 | tail -n1 | -print -exec mv -- {} /archives/recent/downloads/ \; -quit`. tail is important because only chooses the last one folder.

Comment: @f0nzie, `find` doesn't process files that it finds in any particular order (e.g. it doesn't sort them).  See [What is Unix find command's default ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11555243/4154375).  The code that I provided moves the first one that it finds.  If you have a requirement stronger than "will move only one folder", then you need to state it explicitly.  If code using `tail` appears to meet another requirement then (because of the unpredictable order in which `find` processes files in a directory) it is unlikely to do so consistently, particularly as changes occur over time.